# reloaddata make the position of the table view go wrong

Tags: ios

I have a table view which will calculate the height of each cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath will use the result.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
            UITableViewCell *sectionHeaderView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (sectionHeaderView == nil) 
    {
                sectionHeaderView = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
//setting up the cell 
and also calculate the total height required for this cell and save to _eachcellheight
}
```

Its the part for the cell.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 CGPoint offset = tableView.contentOffset;
    [tableView reloadData];
    [tableView setContentOffset:offset];
}
```

In the view will appear, I need to reload the data in the table.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return _eachcellheight; //option 1
   return 200; //option 2
}
```

Now the problem is if using option one the table display at the begining would be fine but after reloaddata offset of the table will go strange and scrolling go strange also.

But using option 2 return a 200.f for all the each, the reloaddata work fine and it can stay in the same position as before.
But the table must have different cell height.

How can I solve it?
I have been solving this problem for three days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `heightForRowAtIndexPath` gets called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Move your height calculation logic inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it will work fine. Table view needs to know height of each cell before it actually creates the cells.

Comment: But the height of each cell I need to calculate base on all the data in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I cant be moved.  Can I same the height to a array that ready for use? Is it possibe?